# Bootstrap columns with equal margin left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying Bootstrap for the first time. I need a pattern something like the following image.

But when I tried the following code, showing weird. I need specific margin left say 20 px on all divs. ( like the picture )

[image]

**My code**

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8 white topm " style="height: 400px;"></div>

            <div class="col-md-4 topm " style="height: 400px;">
                <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 white" style="height: 400px;">d</div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-5 white topm " style="height: 400px;"></div>

            <div class="col-md-7 topm " style="height: 350px;">
                <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 white" style="height: 350px;">d</div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Use jsfiddle for your code to understand and write clear question.

Comment: @ramesh Bootstrap already places the margin when you are using Grid Classes, why you want to explicitly specify this ?

Comment: in bootstrap-3, which I am using, showing padding instead of margin

Comment: Since BS uses padding to create spacing, use containers inside your `col-*` http://bootply.com/112674

Comment: tried that but that time the left div not fitting to the extreme left edge. padding the there

Comment: You may use custom css to get exact result. Such margin-top, margin-right.

Answer (score 0):

after :

```
<div class = "row">
```

use : `<div class="container">`

It should solve your issues.